# Is there an elliptic surface over $Y(1)$?

Tags: modular-forms, ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, elliptic-curves

Actually I have a few related questions.

Here, by $Y(1)$ I mean the affine $j$-line $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash\mathcal{H}$.

I know $Y(1)$ is only a coarse moduli space, so there isn't a universal elliptic curve over it, but **does there exist an elliptic surface over it such that the fiber above every point is the elliptic curve corresponding to that point?**

Now, I know that above the open set $Y(1) \setminus \{i, e^{2\pi i/3}\}$, there is such an elliptic surface. My second question is: **Does there exist an open cover of $Y(1)$ such that above each open set in the cover, there exists an elliptic surface with the above property?** (I'm not asking for the surfaces to glue.)

Complex analytically, one can consider the space:
$$\mathcal{H}\times\mathbb{C}$$
On this space we have an action (on the right) by $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, acting via $$(\tau,x)\cdot(a,b) = (\tau, x + a\tau + b),$$
and an action (on the left) by $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, acting via
$$\gamma\cdot(\tau,x) = (\gamma\tau, x)$$
where $\gamma$ acts on $\mathcal{H}$ by fractional linear transformations. Since intuitively, $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathcal{H}\times\mathbb{C}$ "discretely", so the quotient $\mathcal{H}\times\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ should be a complex manifold, and is essentially an elliptic surface over $\mathcal{H}$.

If $\Gamma \subset \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, then we may also try to form the quotient 
$$\mathbb{E}(\Gamma) := \Gamma\backslash\mathcal{H}\times\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}.$$
Intuitively, if $\Gamma$ has no elliptic elements, then it should act "discretely" on $\mathcal{H}\times\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and the quotient ought to be a manifold. Hence, if $\Gamma = \Gamma(2)$ (ie, matrices congruent to the identity mod 2), then since $\Gamma(2)$ has no elliptic elements, shouldn't $\mathbb{E}(\Gamma(2))$ be a (complex) manifold? If it is, then it's a complex manifold above $Y(2) := \Gamma(2)\backslash\mathcal{H}$, which is again only a coarse moduli scheme, and hence has no universal elliptic curve. In this case, **my third question is: is $\mathbb{E}(\Gamma(2))$algebraic? and if it is, can someone describe heuristically how it's different from a universal elliptic curve over $Y(2)$, if one existed?**

The context for these questions comes from me trying to understand why Katz's definition of modular forms for $\Gamma(N)$ (in his paper on $p$-adic modular forms) is properly a generalization of the analytic definition of modular forms. In particular, I'm trying to understand why they must give holomorphic functions on $\mathcal{H}$. I see why this must be the case when $N \ge 3$, since then you have a universal elliptic curve, and in this case holomorphicity is a result of the required compatibility with base change, but in the case of $N = 1$ and $N = 2$, I'm still a little confused. Relevant references would be appreciated as well.

thanks,

- will

Comment: Dear oxeimon, There is a paper of Igusa from the 50s (if I remember correctly) which shows that the jump in the size of the automorphism group at $j = 0$ and $j = 1728$ provides a local obstruction to constructing a family over a n.h. of either of these $j$-invariants whose $j$-invariant is equal to $j$.    The argument is probably very similar to Will Sawin's below.  Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 The last exercise of Hartshorne chapter 4 section 4 proves that there is no elliptic surface over $\mathbb A^1$ with nonconstant $j$ invariant. Obviously this is a special case.

2 No as well. Put the fiber in Weirstrass form near $j=0$. Then one can write it as $y^2=x^3-g_2x-g_3$, where $g_2$ and $g_3$ are both functions of $j$ that are well-defined at $j=0$. Furthermore clearly $g_3$ is nonvanishing at $j=0$ and $g_2$ is vanishing at $j=0$. Then computing the $j$ invariant near $j=0$ as $g_2^3/(4g_2^3-27g_3^2)$ up to a constant, we see it vanishes to at least third order, an obvious falsehood.

3 Yes, you're thinking of the Legendre family $y^2=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$. The Legendre family is universal up to a quadratic twist - every family with full level two structure is a pullback of Legendre, up to a quadratic twist. So it is as close an approximation to the universal elliptic curve over $Y(2)$ as you can get in the category of schemes.

Comment: I don't think your answer to (2) is quite correct. When counting orders of zeros on $Y(1)$, you have to take ramification into account. Since $j = 0$ at the triply-ramified point $e^{2\pi i/3}$, its order is actually its order as a holomorphic function on $\mathcal{H}$, divided by 3.

Comment: Dear oxeimon, What exactly is your objection?  Regards, 

Comment: Will Sawin's answer is correct.

Comment: @Emerton: I suppose I must be not understanding something. What he seems to be saying is that the j-invariant, as a holomorphic function on the upper half plane, has a triple zero at $\rho := e^{2\pi i /3}$ (though I believe that as a function on Y(1), its divisor is $(\rho) - (i\infty)$, precisely because $\rho$ is a triply ramified point under the cover $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow Y(1)$).

I agree with that statement, but I don't see how this is an obstruction for having an elliptic surface above a neighborhood of $\rho$.

Comment: Dear oxeimon, You are getting confused.  The curve $Y(1)$ is simply the affine line, with coordinate $j$.  You are asking if it is possible to find a family of elliptic curves parameterized by some n.h. around $j = 0$ whose $j$-invariant is equal to the coordinate $j$ itself.  Clearly $j$ vanishes to first order at $j = 0$ (not 3rd order).  On the other hand, if such a family existed, then (writing it in Weierstrass form, which is always possible in a suff. small n.h. of any point) one deduces that in fact $j$ vanishes to third order at $j = 0$.  This is a contradiction, hence no such ...

Comment: ... family exists.  (So Will is *not* asserting that $j$ vanishes to order $3$ at $0$; rather he is *deducing* that this absurd statement would follow if a family of the type you asked for exists, and so by *reductio ad absurdum* concluding that such a family cannot exist.) Regards,

Comment: Dear Emerton, let me paraphrase the argument, and please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong - 

Suppose you have an elliptic surface over some neighborhood of 0 on the $j$-line, then by definition this means that over some trivializing (Zariski) open set (ie, via the definition of a morphism of finite type), the bundle must be given by a weierstrass equation with coefficients in a $\mathbb{C}[j]$-algebra. Since we're in characteristic 0, we can write the equation as $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$, where $A,B$ must be functions of $j$...

Comment: ...But at $j = 0$, $A$ is 0, and yet $j$ is defined as $1728\cdot A^3/(A^3-27B^2)$, and hence $j$ must have a triple zero at $j = 0$, which is obviously false.

My confusion arose from the fact that $g_2, g_3$ are usually thought of as modular forms, which having positive weight, means that they do not descend to functions on the $j$-line. However, taking the example of the elliptic surface above $Y(1)\setminus\{j = 0, j = 1728\}$, the modular forms $g_2, g_3$ in this case do actually give functions on $Y(1)\setminus\{j = 0, j = 1728\}$...

Comment: ...This leads to another question. Is it true that if you have a modular form $f$ of weight $k > 0$ for some finite index subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Will this $f$ always give you a function on the modular curve for $\Gamma$ away from all elliptic points?

- thanks

Comment: Emerson's description of my argument is completely accurate.

Comment: $g_2$ and $g_3$ also appear algebraically, whenever you have an elliptic curve. Modular forms descend to functions when you choose an elliptic surface, then choose a differential on it. One can do this, but there is a lot of choice involved.

Comment: Actually, are you sure that my $\mathbb{E}(\Gamma(2))$ is the same as the legendre family? The latter has singular fibers above $\lambda = 0,1$, whereas my $\mathbb{E}(\Gamma(2))$ has no singular fibers (as far as I can tell). Or am I being stupid again?

Comment: $Y(2)$ is a projective line missing three points. Your $\mathbb E(\Gamma(2))$ is just the Legendre family with the two singular fibers removed.

Comment: Ah, of course. That makes sense.

Thanks Will & Emerton for your help and patience.

- will

Comment: Dear Will, a small point --- my name is Emerton, with a t, not an s.  Cheers, Matt


Comment: Sorry about that. Best, Will